# is it ok to hide admob banners after user click?

Tags: android, admob

Is it ok for android application to hide admob banner after user clicks it?
I.e. user clicks it, returns to application and banners are hidden there (e.g. for 1 hour).
Can it be treated as violation of admob rules? Something like - encourage clicks.

And if it's not ok then how to protect application from high amount of clicking by strangers..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO Admob is unlikely to consider hiding a banner after a click to be against their policies.

Comment: But is it normal practice to hide banner? Or are there better ideas for protection from "overclicking" ?

Comment: It is not normal to hide a banner. My advice is to not worry about users "overclocking". Let Admob handle any abberations.

Answer (score 0):

`You` can use  `mAdView.setVisibility(AdView.INVISIBLE);` 
after user clicks it.

Comment: currently I'm using `adView.setVisibility(View.GONE)`
isn't it the same?

but my question was more about admob rules. Is it allowed?

Answer (score 0):

The difference between `mAdView.setVisibility(AdView.INVISIBLE); and gone, is that the view invisible, still  takes up space  in your layout while gone doesnt.
If you find the option to set it invisible in [developer.android.com][1] , I think that it is allowed.`

Comment: you mean that _invisible_ is allowed, and _gone_ is not allowed?

Comment: NONO sorry, I meant that both of them are allowed. (thats what I think) . It was my mistake not using commas in the right way :-D. Anyway, try it because I tried once that if you clicked the banner, I gave the users extra points and it worked. But anyway, be careful, Admob is really strict Postcript: Did you understand the difference between GONE and INVISBLE?